# Reg Ex to Find at least four spaces or one tab or mixed

Tags: c#, regex

I want to capture the following pattern using Regex in C# and replace it with word 'Merged'

Characters should have at least four spaces or one tab. However they can be mixed

`space space space`             - Invalid - 'Not merged'

`space space space space`      - Valid - 'Merged'

`space space space space space` - Valid - 'Merged'

`space <tab>`                      - Valid - 'Merged'

`<tab><tab>` - Valid - 'Merged'

`space<tab><tab>space` - Valid - 'Merged'

Comment: On its own, this can be satisfied by a trivial alternation: `@"\ {4}|\t"`. Are there any further conditions?

Comment: I want to replace them with a Word for eg Merged

Comment: So you want to match the maximum number of consecutive spaces/tabs, provided that the sequence contains at least 4 spaces or 1 tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
[ ]*\t[ \t]*|[ ]{4,}
```

I represented spaces as `[ ]` to make it clear what is going on, but it will work just as well if you remove the square brackets.

Explanation:

```
  [ ]*      # any number of spaces
  \t        # a single tab
  [ \t]*    # any number of spaces or tabs
|         # OR
  [ ]{4,}   # 4 or more spaces
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/MJYp80iEN1

Here is an alternative that uses a lookahead to check the conditions, then just matches any number of spaces or tabs:

```
(?=[ ]*\t|[ ]{4})[ \t]+
```

Answer (score 1):

`{4,}| *\t[ \t]*`

`{4,}` indicates 4 or more spaces
`|` alternation -- like an `OR` operator between the option above and everything below
`*` zero or more spaces (before the tab below)
`\t` one tab
`[ \t]*` zero or more tabs or spaces after a tab (after the tab above)

Those are single spaces after each `[`.

This allows any combination of spaces and tabs, so long as there is at least one tab, which is how your questions reads. If there are additional constraints in the tab scenario, please comment and I'll update the answer.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @" {4,}|[ \t]*\t[ \t]*", "Merged");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this regex:

`[ \t]*( {4}|*\t)[ \t]*`

It checks the core condition (at least four spaces or a tab), and matches any number of surrounding tabs or spaces (such that you can replace all of the tab/space whitespace).